# I need help solving an integral expression.

Tags: integration, problem-solving

I need help solving this problem.  I know that:
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_0}F(t)\space dt=\frac{t_0^2+t_1^2}{2t_0^2}$$
and I want to find F(t).  I tried taking the derivative of $\frac{t_0^2+t_1^2}{2t_0^2}$,but that didn't result in the needed expression when I re-integrated it.
Can someone show me how to find $F(t)$?

Comment: Did you mix-up $t_0$ and $t_1$? Your integral decreases as $t_0$ increases, while being positive...

Comment: The subscript 0 indicates 'present day', not the order in a monotonically increasing series.  $t$ is time and $t_1$ is earlier than $t_0$.

Comment: If you set $t_1$ to zero, then your integral is constant at $\frac{1}{2}$, which seems impossible for $F\neq 0$

Comment: $\int_0^1 + \int_1^2 \neq \int_0^2$

Comment: Unless there are other conditions, or perhaps a misunderstanding of the situation (is this a cosmology problem?) then citronrose's and Frudrururu's points show that this expression cannot be true whatsoever because it does not obey integral rules.